# How to connect ftps using node and upload the files

Tags: node.js, ftps

I am new in node.js. I want to connect `ftps://ftp.XXX.XXX` using node.js in a passive mode. After a successful connection I want to upload local files to connected ftps.

My code below is working for the ftp but showing timeout for `ftps://ftp.XXX.XXX`.

```
var  Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');

 const config = {
        host: 'XXX.XXXX.net',
        username: 'XXXXX',
        password: 'XXXXX',
        port: 22

      };
     let status= await sftp.connect(config)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('filename===>'+filename); 
        console.log('fullpath===>'+fullpath); 
        sftp.fastPut(fullpath, '/path/to/remote/dir'+filename);
        return 1;
    }).catch(err => {
       console.error(err.message);
        return 0;
    });
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem.
What did you try? What is the expected result? Can you show us some code?
Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it.
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks I have added sample code

Comment: There appears to be a mixup between sftp and ftps (ftp over ssh vs ftp over ssl). These are two different protocols. `ssh2-sftp-client` cannot be used for ftps. Have a look at [this ftp client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp-ext) instead.

Comment: I have to upload the local file to ftps location. does it support? they have provided just upload(readableStream, remoteFilename);

Actually I have to upload csv file from local to server

Comment: Yep, SFTP and FTPS are entirely different beasts. SFTP is a file transfer protocol unrelated to FTP implemented within SSH; FTPS is the original FTP protocol, but wrapped in TLS/SSL.

Comment: Please help me to connect to ftps server using node js. I have tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp-ext but no luck

Comment: giving the following error 

Error: Timeout (control socket)
    at Socket.socket.once (D:\node\decimaHuRequest\node_modules\basic-ftp\dist\F
tpContext.js:310:58)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:442:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
uploadFiletoFtp called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolve. Actually I am trying to connect [box.com](http://box.com/) ftps account and they have provided the hooks on event of upload so I have used those hook to implement functionality